# Can't get friend list via graph facebook API

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api

I have a problem when get list friend facebook using Graph API in iOS.

I'm used `/{user-id}/friends` to get list friend and result is `friends who have used (via Facebook Login) the app making the request` not list friend.

After that I'm try get friend on `Graph API Explorer`, I get expected result.

Then I use `access_token` on `Graph API Explorer` to replace access_token got via login in iOS. I also get expected result.

What different access_token on `Graph API Explorer` and access_token get via login?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can achieve this using the facebook SDK for iOS or using the graph API.

If you're using the sdk you can make the request as

```
* make the API call */
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/{friendlist-id}"
                             parameters:nil
                             HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                      completionHandler:^(
                          FBRequestConnection *connection,
                          id result,
                          NSError *error
                      ) {
                          /* handle the result */
                      }];
```

You will need a user acess token and read_friendlists permission. You can also use the graph api explorer to test

More info here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/friendlist